# How can I convert javascript var obj = {}; to C#?

Tags: javascript, c#

I have the following javascript code:

```
var key = "Mykey" + NextNumber.toString();
var value = {"Name":"Tony","Width":"150","Height":"320"};
var valuejson = JSON.stringify(value);
var obj = {};
obj[key] = valuejson
```

I know how to create valuejson in C#, but I don't know how to create something similar like var obj = {}; in C#. How can I do that in C#?

key and valuejson in C#:

```
 public class MyValue
 {
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Width { get; set; }
     public string Height { get; set; }
 }

 MyValue value = new MyValue();
 value.Name = "Tony";
 value.Width = "150";
 value.Height = "320";
 string jsonValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
 string key = "Mykey" + NextNumber.toString();
```

Comment: you can use a ``Dictionary`` in c# to do this : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: or an anonymous object `new {Name = "Tony", Width = "150", Height = "320"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use a [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) object which works similar to `{}` in javascript... But... You have to be CAREFUL, example:

```
public class test 
{
    public class MyValue
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Width { get; set; }
        public string Height { get; set; }
    }

    public void testing() 
    {
        MyValue value = new MyValue();
        value.Name = "Tony";
        value.Width = "150";
        value.Height = "320";
        dynamic jsonValue = new { keyA = value };
        string height = jsonValue.keyA.Height;
    }
}
```

**EDI:**

Actually, I read a bit more carefully your need, and a dictionary can also suit your needs:

```
public class test
{
    public class MyValue
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Width { get; set; }
        public string Height { get; set; }
    }

    Dictionary<string, MyValue> dic = new Dictionary<string, MyValue>();
    public void testing()
    {
        string key = "Mykey" + NextNumber.toString();

        MyValue value = new MyValue();
        value.Name = "Tony";
        value.Width = "150";
        value.Height = "320";

        dic.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

Since you where asking for the equivalent of a `var x = {}` I suggested the `dynamic` but I see you want to create a key and associate that value to that key.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an object whose members can be dynamically added and removed at run time (like in Javascript) then the [ExpandoObject class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.8) should fit your needs.

```cs
dynamic employee = new ExpandoObject();
employee.Name = "John Smith";
employee.Age = 33;

foreach (var property in (IDictionary<String, Object>)employee)
{
    Console.WriteLine(property.Key + ": " + property.Value);
}
// This code example produces the following output:
// Name: John Smith
// Age: 33
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert from a json string to a C# object, you can use the `DeserializeObject` method and pass in an instance of the c# object that you want to convert this json to. The `JsonConvert` library is part of the Newtonsoft.Json library.

```
 var converted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myCSharpViewModel>(json);
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.

Comment: I've added a bit. It could be improved upon for sure - I welcome edits ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for `dynamic` `ExpandoObject`.

Example:

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();

obj.banana = "CIAO";
obj.bidshmqwq = 11245;
obj.BRUFCJMWH = null;
```

In substance, this `Type` can let you declare object's properties dynamically.